# What does a *.sql file contain

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

In Vsual Studio => Server Explorer I created a new SQL Server database (dbo) and I right clicked on the option "publish to provider".
It generated a file with sql extension which includes sql commands (SELECT, UPDATE).

I want to know what does this file contain.

Is it the whole database?

Can I import this file to SQL Server Management Studio later?

And does it store everything in database (relations, default values, rules)?

I have written some of the text from the file

```
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK__aspnet_Me__Appli__21B6055D]    Script Date: 06/30/2013      12:01:32 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].  [FK__aspnet_Me__Appli__21B6055D]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].  [aspnet_Membership]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__aspnet_Me__Appli__21B6055D]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK__aspnet_Me__UserI__22AA2996]    Script Date: 06/30/2013   12:01:32 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].  [FK__aspnet_Me__UserI__22AA2996]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]. [aspnet_Membership]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__aspnet_Me__UserI__22AA2996]
GO
/***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i clicked [...] can i import this file to sql server management studio later?

Then look at the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585(v=vs.100).aspx) for what you clicked on:

> The Database Publishing Wizard in Visual Studio enables you to deploy a SQL Server database (both schema and data) to a hosting environment. You can run the wizard by right-clicking a database in Server Explorer and then clicking Publish to provider.
>
> The tool supports the following ways to deploy a database:
>
> - **It can generate a single SQL script file that you can manually run on the target server to re-create the database schema and the database contents.**

So, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This file contains a list of SQL statements that will transform the DB you selected during the process.

This file will work only for a DB in the same state as the one you selected.

If you will run this process twice, the script that will be generated will be different, since the first script changed your db, and some operations will not be performed.

This file does not contain all the data in the DB.